# How to prove a function is not onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $f : Z\to Z$ be the function defined by $f(x) = 3x + 1$. Prove that $f $ is not onto, using a proof by contradiction. (Choose an integer $n$, and then prove ($\forall m \in Z$)($f(m) ≠ n$) by contradiction.)

so far I have:
\begin{gather*}
    1.\quad \text{Let}\quad y  = -1     \qquad   \text{assumption}\\
    2. \quad \text{Let}\quad f(x) = -1       \qquad \text{hypothesis}\\
    3. \quad 3x+1 = -1        \qquad \text{Definition of $f (2)$}\\
    4. \quad 3x  = -2            \qquad \text{Algebra}\\
    5. \quad x = -2/3          \qquad \text{Algebra}
\end{gather*}

What else is needed? I don't know where to go from here?

Comment: Yes it is right.

Comment: ok so what i have so far is correct? I don't know what else to do I'm stuck??

Comment: Indeed you have shown a counterexample to the supposition that $f$ is onto. You only need one. You proceed by putting a period on the end of this result and move on. Note that (Ɐm € Z)(f(m) ≠ n) is gibberish to me.

Comment: Okay I get it since (-2/3) is not an integer I have finished it, however, I feel like there are more steps where I state (-2/3) is not an integer? how would i write that out?

Comment: How about "Since $-\frac{2}{3}$ is not an integer, $f$ is not onto".

Comment: @J.W.Perry okay thanks. I guess I over thought the problem lol

Comment: @jrsk8chivas You probably did over think the problem, but I think that makes me very happy. I wish you were one of my students, not that I am not very happy with my current students. I cannot say anything bad about "over thinking" in these matters. It is certainly better than under thinking.  :)

Comment: @Bungo You would probably be the appropriate person to post an answer to this question (if you feel like it) by copying your comment into answer, thus taking this out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

Your work shows that the only real number $x$ for which $f(x)=−1$ is $x=−2/3$. In particular, there is no integer $n$ such that $f(n)=−1$. Since the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb Z$, the set of integers, you can conclude that $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 0):

y=3x+1 is not onto because x=(y-1)/3 which does not belong to Z rather belong to R. hence we can say there does not exist any integer x corresponding to any integer in codomain y for which f(x)=y hence f is not onto

Answer (score -2):

Let $y=3x+1$ be any element in $\mathbb Z$, then $x=\frac{y-1}{3}$. So, 
$$f(x) = f\left(\frac{y-1}{3}\right) = 3\frac{y-1}{3} + 1 = y$$
Thus, by Definition of onto function we conclude that given function is onto.